# Texture Transparency with Unreal (See through walls)

Tags: opengl, transparency, direct3d, alpha, unreal-development-kit

We are working on porting some software from Windows to MacOS.

When we bring up a texture with an alpha channel, the pixels that are fully Opaque work as expected, pixels that are Fully transparent work as expected (You can see the wall behind).

However, pixels that are semi-transparent >0% opacity and < 100% opacity, render poorly and you are able to see through the wall behind and you can see the skybox through the texture and the wall behind it.

I know you will likely need more information and I will be happy to provide. I am not looking for a quick fix solution, I really have just run out of ideas and need someone else to take a guess as whats wrong.

I will post the solution and correct answer goes to whoever pointed me that way.

It is not the texture being placed right on the wall, it is placed on a static mesh close to the wall.

(Unable to post images as this is my first question here)

Comment: Which specific engine (and version) are you using? (UE1, UE2, UE3?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are [sorting transparent objects by depth](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Transparency_Sorting), yes? I gather from your question, the answer will be no.

You cannot just render transparent objects the way you do opaque ones. Your renderer is just a fancy triangle drawer. As such, it has no real concept of objects, or even transparency. You achieve transparency by blending the transparent pixels with whatever happens to be in the framebuffer at the time you draw the transparent triangle.

It simply cannot know what it is you intend to draw behind the triangle later. Therefore, the general method for transparent objects is to:

1. Render all opaque objects first.
2. Render transparent objects sorted back-to-front. Also, turn off depth writes (depth tests are fine).

Comment: Thank you Nicol, Would you be able to explain why Fully transparent portions of the image work properly?

Comment: @AndrewTarzwell: Are you using alpha testing for those pixels?

Comment: While looking into this, I found that some "#ifdef'd" code may not have been defined, which may have something to so with this issue. If it's working correctly yes, ALPHA_TEST should be on. I'll know if this makes a difference after rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be an answer but might useful.
Making an object which applies a transparent texture in Maya/3d MAX and export as fbx and import to unreal ?